# How can I modify the variable named in a dataframe cell?

Tags: r

I'm trying to modify a "variable" variable; that is to say, I wish to modify only that variable whose name matches the text in a cell of a dataframe/matrix.

For example, if `matrix1[1,1] == "Rupert"`, I want to perform an operation on the variable Rupert (say, `Rupert <- Rupert + 1`). But if `matrix1[1,1] == "Paddington"`, I want to perform the operation on the Paddington variable instead.

I've discovered the `assign()` function which allows me *create* new variables whose name is that of the text in a matrix, but I haven't been able to figure out how to *modify* variables in a similar fashion.

Thanks for your attention,

Alistair

Comment: `assign` will also overwrite the variable. `get` will get it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your example:

```
var <- matrix1[1,1]
assign(var,get(var)+1)
```

The `get` function can be found in the "See also" section of `help(assign)`.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help Frank. For anyone else who stumbles across this question: note that you **cannot** assign variables using `assign(matrix1[1,1],3)`. The correct code is `assign(paste(matrix1[1,1],"", sep = ""),3)` - you *must* use the "paste" command in there (not sure why). Similarly, if you wish to apply Franks answer in the manner I'm attempting to, the correct code is `assign(paste(matrix1[1,1],"", sep = ""),get(paste(matrix1[1,1],"", sep = ""))+3)`.

Comment: Huh, I did not know that. Things soon get tricky when you rely on `assign` and `get`. I think most R users would advise you to avoid them if possible. I'm not an expert but I think the reasoning is: Besides requiring trickier code, the approach is also computationally costly and leaves you with tons of objects in your namespace that you might accidentally forget had earlier been defined.